# Protocol Agnostic Cron Task

Tags: curl, cron

Im trying to set up CRON tasks so they are agnostic of the protocol used.

In this case Im using CRON to trigger CURL. Moving a server to SSL Protocol and am looking for a way to change CRON once in case code needs to be reverted temporarily.

`*/8 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://www.example.com/directory/awesome_file.php`

Is it possible to have CURL not care about the protocol? If I attempt this in BASH directly I get:

`curl //www.site.com/directory/awesome_file.php
curl: (3) <url> malformed`

Answer (score 0):

Differing use case scenario, but the answer was in the comments here:
[How To Use cURL without http://www Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265702/how-to-use-curl-without-http-www-prefix)

By: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837684/mith

Simply remove the protocol and use the raw domain.

In this case:
`curl site.com/directory/awesome_file.php`