# Basic authentication not working with cUrl

Tags: php, curl

I am facing a weird situation. I am POSTing data to a remote server using cUrl and the server requires basic HTTP authentication using $username and $password. The POSTable data is in $postargs

```
$process = curl_init();
curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

When I cURL to http://example.com the cURL return "401 Uauthorized" message from the remote server. 
When I cURL to http://www.example.com it authenticates me correctly BUT the POSTed fields are not read by the remote server! I did a "print_r($_POST)" on the remote server and it prints an emtpty array even though the $postargs on the calling server are set correctly. Why could this be happening??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cUrl a domain without http://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867430/curl-a-domain-without-http-www)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got cUrl installed in your machine? That is one of the most common cases.

If yes, then there is a good chance your curl_init() has some problems. You should debug it, using var_dump().

If you need to read something about it, use this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php).

Comment: cURL is obviously installed on the machine else it wouldn't work at all! It IS working when I use "www" in the remote URL but the then POSTed vars are not sent over. When I remove the "www" the authorization fails.

Comment: Then please check this one, it is the exact problem I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867430/curl-a-domain-without-http-www